# Include the Matched A-Z in the Result Using RegEx

Tags: regex, parsing, html-parsing

I'm trying to use regex to parse out
    
tags.  I've got the regex almost as what I need it to be, with one small problem.  The problem is, the regex isn't including the first letter of the match it finds.  I'll show you what I mean...first, here is the regex I'm using right now:

```
(?<=h1.*\>[a-zA-Z0-9])(.*?)(?=\<\/)
```

And lets say the HTML code I was looking to parse the
    
tags out of looked like this:

```
<h1 align="center"><strong><font color="#FF0000">I'm an H1 Tag!!</font></strong></h1>
```

The regex I'm using matches this out of the above HTML code:

'm an H1 Tag!!

So as you can see, it is leaving out the first part of the match (the "I" in "I'm").

So my question is, how can I use the regex I've got thus far to match the way I have it set up, but to include the first letter or number it finds (if it finds one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should include the first letter in the bracket

```
(?<=h1.*\>([a-zA-Z0-9]).*?)(?=\<\/)
```

Comment: You were close Jan Turon, but you gave me the idea to get the right answer to my own question, so thanks.  Anyway, here is what it is that works:

    (?<=h1.*\>)[a-zA-Z0-9](.*?)(?=\<\/)

I'd "Answer My Own Question" but I don't have enough "reputation" to do it, so I've just got to put the answer in a comment.